# Как проверить является ли строка числом, если она содержит русские символы?

Tags: c++, строки

Написал функцию, которая проверяет каждый символ строки до тех пор, пока не встретит **не цифру** или терминирующий ноль. Если встречается **не цифра**, то функция возвращает 0. Если на всём пути не встретиалсь **не цифра**, возвращает 1.

Проблема в том, что она не работает со строками, которые содеражт русские символы, так как их численные значения не входят в диапозон от -1 до 255.

```
int is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (s[count])
    {
        if (isdigit(s[count]))
            ++count;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

1. Почему русские символы не входят в данный диапозон?
2. Почему то, что русские символы не входят в диапозон, влияет на работу функции(т.е. выдаётся ошибка)?
3. Что нужно сделать с моим кодом, чтобы функция корректно работала со строками, содержащие русские символы?

Comment: @Harry когда навожу на строку, то показывает, что она содержит кол-во символов в ней + 1. Из этого сделал такой вывод.

Comment: Приведите пример строк (обязательно с указанием их кодировки), на которых эта функция работает некорректно.

Comment: Русские буквы одновременно входят и не входят в этот диапазон. Вот такая закавыка.

Comment: Что-то сомнительное утверждение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что делаете вы, проще сделать так:

```
bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    return !s.empty() && (s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == s.npos);
}
```

Ваша проблема, думаю, в том, что `isdigit()` работает с тем, что "представимо как `unsigned char`", так что попробуйте так -

```
   if (isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[count])))
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы ответить на первый и второй вопрос из моего поста?

Comment: 1. Почему вы решили, что не входят? 2. Почему вы решили, что дело именно в этом? https://ideone.com/739bCT А вот - с вашей функцией, но нормально написанной: https://ideone.com/eF9ITn Как видите, русский не мешает...

Comment: @Harry,   string::npos  статический член..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan И что? мне так меньше писать на 5 букв, а обратиться так я имею полное право...

Comment: @Harry 1. Когда прошёлся дебагером по строке, в которой были записаны русские символы, то увидел, что значение каждого символа имеет отрицательный знак; 2. Потому что в ошибке, которую выдал компилятор было написано : "Expression c>= -1 && c <= 255"

Comment: `char` может быть и знаковым, и беззнаковым - в зависимости от реализации. Приведите полный код с ошибкой - у вас был слет на вашей функции? Где именно? С каким компилятором работаете? Словом, хотелось бы [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: В С++17 строка обязана заканчиваться нулевым символом, то бишь обращение к `str[str.size()]` является определенным поведением и возвращает `\0`

Comment: @Harry вот полный код: https://ideone.com/yIcq5v, комментарием указал место слёта. Но почему то на данном сайте написано "успешно"... Работаю в Visual Studio 2019

Comment: @VTT [Тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) пишут о таком только для константной строки... Но в принципе да, в конкретной функции ТС это должно работать.

Comment: А с каким компилятором работаете? скорее всего `isdigit` в нем реализована так, что работает корректно только с ASCII (в строгом смысле) значениями... В принципе он заточен по стандарту под `unsigned char`, так что - `bool my_isdigit(char ch)
{
    return std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
}`

Comment: только для константной строки было в *(until C++11)*

Comment: @Harry в Visual Studio 2019

Comment: @VTT Всегда верил cppreference.com :) - неужто и у них бывают такие проколы? Впрочем, я в любом случае с древних времен приучен использовать `c_str()`... Впрочем, в любом случае к проблеме в задаче это отношения не имеет, а ответ я сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Так а у них правильно написано же. *If pos == size(), a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character) is returned. For the first (non-const) version, the behavior is undefined if this character is modified to any value other than CharT() .*

Comment: @ Ваше изменение работает, но не могли бы Вы мне объяснить, что значит эта строчка: `static_cast<unsigned char>(s[count])`

Comment: Приведение `s[count]` типа `char` к типу `unsigned char`, каковое требуется для работы `isdigit`.

Comment: @Harry почему не так: `(unsigned char)(s[count])`?

Comment: `isdigit` требует `int`, а приведение к `unsigned char` может понадобится для сохрания правильного знака

Comment: @iwannaknow Потому, что это не C.

Comment: @VTT но по сути это эквивалентно? Или по какой-то другой схеме приводится к unsigned char в случае C

Comment: @iwannaknow В данном случае результат будет таким же, однако средство не адекватное. Вот муху можно пришибить мухобойкой, а можно загнать под шкаф и отпилить ножки. C-style cast соответствует второму варианту.